# retain property points to wrong address

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have singleton class with ivar named formatter. There is some code:

```
@interface SettingsController : NSObject {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter;  
}

@property (nonatomic,retain,readwrite)  NSDateFormatter *formatter;




@implementation SettingsController

@synthesize formatter,;

SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(SettingsController);

-(id)init
{
 if ( (self = [super init]) )
  {
        ...
        self.formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        ...
  }
```

Problem is that sometime when I try to get this formatter that how:

```
[[SettingsController sharedSettingsController] formatter]
```

The value is missed. There NSDate,NSString or even my own class instance at address that formatter points.

I've try use [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] but only [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] retain] make problem disappear.

How could it be, when I use @property (nonatomic,**retain**,readwrite) and never reset this ivar to another value?

**EDITE:** After I made subclass for NSDateFormatter, I've clearly and easy seen the release that make fall app. **Thanks a lot to progrmr!**

Comment: Something must be sending release to the formatter you allocated but I don't see where from the code you posted.  If you really want to find out, make a subclass of NSDateFormatter and use that in place of NSDateFormatter, override release in the subclass (be sure to call super release), then set a breakpoint in that release function to see all the places it is called from.

Comment: Hmm...Thanks. Will do so and post results!

Answer (score 1):

You write about class `SettingsController`, but are using class `SyncProgress`. Which is it?

If you properly `@synthesize`d the `@property`, what you did in the `init` method you show should be correct, assuming you **don't release** the property -- or at least the same object, from whatever reference to it you may have -- later on, either in the same method or elsewhere. In other words, **don't release an autoreleased item**.

FWIW, the [article that describes the macro](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) says that you should declare

```
+ (SettingsController *) sharedSettingsController;
```

I can't see you doing that, so did you?

And you are **using** class `SyncProgress`, not `SettingsController`. Assuming you declared that as singleton too, you should do the same for `SyncProgress`:

```
+ (SyncProgress *) sharedSyncProgress;
```

What is the `init` method for `SyncProgress`? Do you set the `formatter` there too, and does it even have one? **Or are you just looking at the wrong class**?